# Video metadata cannot be edited

Tags: video, metadata, exiftool

I have an MP4 video that I recorded on my iPhone through whatsapp. While I was copying it to my computer I noticed that the metadata was wrong, so I tried to edit it through ExifTool. Unfortunately, I have been unable to do so, as when trying to edit the Media Create Date field I got the following error message:

```
Warning: Sorry, Media is not writable  
Nothing to do.
```

What can I do to force this edit?

I am pasting the entire metadata field below.

```
File Name                       : 1A716062-7979-4F73-B5E3-713FA3F75CE7.mp4  
Directory                       : .  
File Size                       : 14 MB  
File Modification Date/Time     : 2022:08:09 12:43:59+02:00  
File Access Date/Time           : 2022:08:20 18:47:12+02:00  
File Creation Date/Time         : 2022:08:06 14:28:02+02:00  
File Permissions                : -rw-rw-rw-  
File Type                       : MP4  
File Type Extension             : mp4  
MIME Type                       : video/quicktime  
Major Brand                     : Apple QuickTime (.MOV/QT)  
Minor Version                   : 0.0.0  
Compatible Brands               : qt  
Movie Header Version            : 0  
Create Date                     : 2022:08:09 10:43:00  
Modify Date                     : 2022:08:09 10:43:01  
Time Scale                      : 600  
Duration                        : 7.47 s  
Preferred Rate                  : 1  
Preferred Volume                : 100.00%  
Preview Time                    : 0 s  
Preview Duration                : 0 s  
Poster Time                     : 0 s  
Selection Time                  : 0 s  
Selection Duration              : 0 s  
Current Time                    : 0 s  
Next Track ID                   : 3  
Track Header Version            : 0  
Track Create Date               : 2022:08:09 10:43:00  
Track Modify Date               : 2022:08:09 10:43:01  
Track ID                        : 1  
Track Duration                  : 7.47 s  
Track Layer                     : 0  
Track Volume                    : 100.00%  
Balance                         : 0  
Audio Format                    : mp4a  
Audio Channels                  : 1  
Audio Bits Per Sample           : 16  
Audio Sample Rate               : 48000  
Purchase File Format            : mp4a  
Matrix Structure                : 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1  
Image Width                     : 1080  
Image Height                    : 1920  
Clean Aperture Dimensions       : 1080x1920  
Production Aperture Dimensions  : 1080x1920  
Encoded Pixels Dimensions       : 1080x1920  
Media Header Version            : 0  
Media Create Date               : 2022:08:09 10:43:00  
Media Modify Date               : 2022:08:09 10:43:01  
Media Time Scale                : 600  
Media Duration                  : 7.47 s  
Media Language Code             : und  
Graphics Mode                   : ditherCopy  
Op Color                        : 32768 32768 32768  
Handler Class                   : Data Handler  
Handler Vendor ID               : Apple  
Handler Description             : Core Media Data Handler  
Compressor ID                   : avc1  
Source Image Width              : 1080  
Source Image Height             : 1920  
X Resolution                    : 72  
Y Resolution                    : 72  
Compressor Name                 : H.264  
Bit Depth                       : 24  
Video Frame Rate                : 30.127  
Apple Photos Originating Signature: AdnDrXiTobNxzEGY5ZMa8LzYn8ko  
Creation Date                   : 2022:08:06 04:29:43+02:00  
Handler Type                    : Metadata  
Date Acquired                   : 2022:08:06 10:43:00  
Media Data Size                 : 14349298  
Media Data Offset               : 5077  
Image Size                      : 1080x1920  
Megapixels                      : 2.1  
Avg Bitrate                     : 15.4 Mbps  
Rotation                        : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing your actual command, but I suspect by what you do list (`Media is not writable`) that you are using the tag description (`Media Create Date`) and not the actual tag name (`MediaCreateDate`).  See [exiftool's FAQ #2 and #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q2). Use the command in FAQ #3 to see tag names instead of descriptions, as tag names may be different that just removing spaces from the tag description.

Another thing to take note of is that the `Media*Date`, `Track*Date`, `CreateDate`, and `ModifyDate` are supposed to be set to UTC according to the spec. The time zone shift needs to be taken into account before deciding if the embedded time stamp is correct.  When listing the output you can add the [`-api QuickTimeUTC` option](https://exiftool.org/ExifTool.html#QuickTimeUTC) and exiftool will adjust the date/times to the local time of the computer.